# No routes matched location "/"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I was trying to hit route "/" to render Home component. The component is getting rendered but on the console I am getting:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:3973 No routes matched location "/"  
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:39008:24)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:38933:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:38367:23)
    at App
```

This is my **App.js** file:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import GithubState from "./context/github/GithubState";
import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import User from "./components/users/User";
import About from "./components/pages/About";

import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <GithubState>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/user/:username" element={<User />} />
          </Routes>
        </GithubState>

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Kindly help me out here.

Comment: i think you get that error because you have 2 sets of `Routes` and each one is trying to render `/` but that root is not defined for your second set. does it work like this?: `<Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
        <GithubState>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/user/:username" element={<User />} />
        </GithubState>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    </Routes>
</Router>;`

Comment: ```<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />``` check if this helps

Comment: @kevin adding exact doesn't help...showing the same error

Comment: @coglialoro...it would throw error if you bring GithubState inside Routes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is because you are rendering two `Routes` components and the second doesn't have a route path matching the current path `"/"`.

Merge your `Routes` components so you render a route with path `"/"`. Creating a layout route to render the `GithubState` provider will help a lot here.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const GithubStateLayout = () => (
  <GithubState>
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render out here
  </GithubState>
);
```

...

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Route element={<GithubStateLayout />} >
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/user/:username" element={<User />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add Link tag after the Routes tag and add Link in the import, so you can overcome the issue you are facing. Hope so it helps you.

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.  @Kranthi Yadav.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33450811)